# cellRenderer single cell height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, datagrid, cellrenderer

How do you change the height of a single cell.

```
override protected function drawLayout():void {
    textField.width = this.width;
    height = 64;

    textField.height = height;
    textField.setTextFormat(tf);
    super.drawLayout();
}
```

How do I get the dataGrad to resize the entire row? I'm using a height of 64. but the idea is that it would be dynamic.

Comment: Do you have the `variableRowHeight=true` property set on your data grid?

Comment: `variableRowHeight` is not available in as3

Comment: It's not available even if you use the `setStyle` function? `myDataGrid.setStyle("variableRowHeight", true);`